# Pull the active list node item in 2nd position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items. I have node id of the 'active' class.
I want to get the active flex node_id and pull the active list item to the center position. I want to match the active_slide node_id with list item class and pull the item to center position.

eg: 233 is 'active_slide'. I want to compare the node_id and pull the list item  and pull the item to center position like 69,233,299

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
setTimeout(function(){ 
var node_id = $('.flex-active-slide .node_id').text();
   $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
     $('.'+node_id+'li:eq(1)').before($('.thumbnailIcon li:eq(2)'));
   }); 
},1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slide">
    <div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
      
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>222</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li> 
      <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
<a href="#" class="flex-next">click<a>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>333</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
       <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
     
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
```

Comment: Isn't there a space missing in `$('.'+node_id+'li:eq(1)')` before `li:eq(1)`?

Comment: can you plz provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `item` element you already get from `each` and then re-order the `li` by `insertAfter`:

See a Fiddle here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      var node_id = $('.flex-active-slide .node_id').text();
      $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
         $(item).find('.'+node_id).insertAfter($(item).find('li:eq(2)'));
      }); 
   },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slide">
    <div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>222</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li> 
      <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
<a href="#" class="flex-next">click<a>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="node_id"><span>333</span></div>
    <ul class="thumbnailIcon">
      <li>left</li>  
      <li class="233">1</li>
      <li class="69">2</li>
      <li class="299">3</li>
      <li>right</li>  
    </ul> 
</li>
```